# Formating an Oracle timestamp with PHP

Tags: php, oracle, date, time, timestamp

I want to separate Date and time from retrieved timestamp in oracle with php but it's not working.  I tried to separate date and working after that i have to separate time but i am getting empty timestamp.

```
$db = $row['CREATEDATE']; // CREATEDATE=03-SEP-15 12.55.17.000000 PM

echo 'db...'.(string)$db."<br/>";
$timestamp = strtotime((string)$db);
echo 'timestamp...'.$timestamp."<br/>";
echo date("m-d-Y", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Do you get an empty string for all the "echo"? If no, why don't you let us see the actual content of the $row variable?

Comment: $db is not a string? and what is the date and time format you need?

Comment: i have mentioned the value of CREATEDATE

Answer (score 0):

Convert your received column data to a string, and convert it to a datetime. Then you can do all other formatting on it.

```
$db = $row['CREATEDATE'];         //$db need to be converted to string type
$datetime = new DateTime((string)$db);   //I expect (string)$db will considered as a string 
$date =  $datetime->format('Y M d');   //convert to date 
$time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');    //convert to time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$select_stmt = "select to_char(ENDTIME,' hh24:mi:ss') AS CHENG,to_char(RESERVETIME,' hh24:mi:ss') AS CHENG2 FROM RESERVATION WHERE RESERVATIONSTATUS='RENTING' AND RESERVATIONFACILITY = '".$_SESSION['cno']."'"; 
$stid = oci_parse($con, $select_stmt); 
                        oci_execute($stid); 

                        while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid))
                        {

                            $datt=$row["CHENG"];
                            $datt2=$row["CHENG2"];
                        }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)